# OpenAI Function Call using Langchain returns inconsistent response

Tags: openai-api, langchain, function-call

I have a question for folks who have already tried out OpenAI function calling with Langchain. I am not getting a consistent response from Langchain.

Sometimes I get the below response, where the value is present in `additional_kwargs.function_call` attribute.

```
AIMessage {
  lc_serializable: true,
  lc_kwargs: {
    content: '',
    additional_kwargs: { function_call: [Object], tool_calls: undefined }
  },
  lc_namespace: [ 'langchain', 'schema' ],
  content: '',
  name: undefined,
  additional_kwargs: {
    function_call: {
      name: 'orderPizza',
      arguments: '{\n  "pizzaSize": "NA",\n  "pizzaType": "NA"\n}'
    },
    tool_calls: undefined
  }
}
```

And sometimes I get another response shared below, where `additional_kwargs.function_call` value is undefined.

```
AIMessage {
  lc_serializable: true,
  lc_kwargs: {
    content: '{\n  "function": "functions.welcomeUser",\n  "arguments": {}\n}',
    additional_kwargs: { function_call: undefined, tool_calls: undefined }
  },
  lc_namespace: [ 'langchain', 'schema' ],
  content: '{\n  "function": "functions.welcomeUser",\n  "arguments": {}\n}',
  name: undefined,
  additional_kwargs: { function_call: undefined, tool_calls: undefined }
}
```

The user message that generated the first response is `I want to order pizza` and the user message that generated the second response is `Hey`.

In both cases, it looks like OpenAI can identify the correct function to call. For the first case, the function to be called is `orderPizza` and for the second case the function to be called is `welcomeUser`. The only issue here is that the response is not consistent. In the second response, the function name is present in the JSON body of the `content` attribute instead of `additional_kwargs.function_call`.

Following are my function schemas:

```
const greetUserSchema = {
    name: "welcomeUser",
    description:
      "This function is used for greeting users. Acknowledging the user with a welcome message.",
    parameters: {},
};


const pizzaOrderFunctionSchema = {
    name: "orderPizza",
    description:
      "This function is called to accept the pizza orders. If the pizza size or the pizza type is not mentioned then pass the value as NA in the parameters.",
    parameters: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        pizzaSize: {
          type: "string",
          description: "The size of the pizza",
          enum: ["NA", "small", "medium", "large"],
        },
        pizzaType: {
          type: "string",
          description: "The type of pizza",
          enum: ["NA", "cheese", "pepperoni", "veggie"],
        },
      },
      required: ["pizzaSize", "pizzaType"],
    },
};
```

I wanted to know if this is something expected or if there is any bug in my code because of which I am getting inconsistent results. TIA